# How can I use shadows on an Avatar component in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to make a box shadow for the **Avatar component** on Material UI.
I saw in the documentations: `https://material-ui.com/system/shadows/#shadows` I should just use something like `boxShadow={1}` and import shadows: `import { shadows } from '@material-ui/system';`
but it inst working for me.

Comment: Hi @Luaa, do you have some more code you could provide us? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Halmon I do not have any errors, but i can give you the code:
`<Avatar className="pfp" src={user.photo} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! how?
I did it like this:

```js
// On the Avatar component
<Avatar 
   className="MuiSvgAvatar-root pfp"
   src={user.photo}
/>
```

and on the css part I did:

```css
.pfp:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
    transition: box-shadow 100ms;
}
```